# Jenkins - trigger by email only when certain files change

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins, build, config

I use Email-ext plugin on Jenkins to receive by email the changed files every build.
I'm using the $CHANGES variable in this way:

```
${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS, reverse=true, showPaths=true}
```

Before any build.

I would like to create a special trigger to send me an email only when *.config file changes.
I understand it's suppose to be somehow as a groovy script as a trigger but i'm not sure how.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: usually I'd not assign this task to jenkins but put that into a commit hook of the repository which analyses the commit(s) and sends e-mails accordingly

Comment: I use bitbucket, and i was researching their webhooks a bit. didn't find something that specific.
Do you have any idea?